# ecommerce application web tier/presentation layer unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, web-applications, tdd, e-commerce, bdd

We have had some success using selenium and web driver along with Jbehave. just wanted to know what others are using for unit testing the web tier of any web application? 
the reason i am asking is , writing web driver test cases along with jbehave makes the unit testing very complicated and in more cases, it is taking more time then writing an actual JSP page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas for unit testing a web tier:

1. Use MVC for doing web development. It is pretty easy to unit test controllers assuming you extract all your dependencies.
2. Make liberal use of interfaces to extract dependencies in your JSP pages. For example, does your JSP make a database call? Consider making an Repository interface and then have implementations like MySQLRepositoryImpl.java that implement the interface. This way, you can also "mock" the interface and create a fake database that will run fast in your unit tests.
3. For very difficult problems where you absolutely need to use a dependency, you can get embedded versions of things like web servers (Grizzly, Jetty) or even databases (H2, SQLite).
4. Make sure you write your code such that each function does one thing and one thing only. This will take some refactoring, but it makes testing so much easier.

Comment: We certainly use MVC but that does not solve the problem of creating unit test cases for every complex pages intern every iframes,css selectors, check boxes inside the form , images , conditional Advertisment targets etc.,.. in nutshell,I wanted to be able to write unit test cases for presentation/web tier like i create junit for back end or middle ware modules.